# How to have fixed height and auto width for a div containing objects with inline-block display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Normally if you have a div with fixed width and auto height and you add into it, objects with defined width and height and inline-block display, they get added side by side each other within the div until it runs out of width and the height than automatically increases so that they can be accommodated below.

I want to figure out a way to reverse this functionality. A div with fixed height and auto width. As objects(with defined width and height and inline-block display) get added to it they get added below each other until the div runs out of height and then the width automatically increases to accommodate them from the top right. I tried the example below but it didn't work.

the css (didn't work)

```
.div {

    height:300px;
    width:auto;

}
```

The width didn't increase and it caused the div to vertically overflow. I know what I am trying to do is pretty common these days though I can't remember where I have last seen it. Perhaps it requires javascript. I am open to anything and everything. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty good example of where [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) comes in handy:

```css
.testbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 300px;
  background: chocolate;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="testbox">
  <span class="item">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  <span class="item">2 Soluta officia aut dolorem, doloribus!</span>
  <span class="item">3 Accusamus et quibusdam aliquid ullam.</span>
  <span class="item">4 Magnam fugit temporibus, minus ut?</span>
  <span class="item">5 Laborum corporis quidem eum esse.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript isn't needed, we can do this with CSS columns.

On your parent element, set the maximum width, and specify a column width (you may need to include vendor prefixes)

```
.parent {
   width: 300px;
  -moz-column-width: 100px;
  -webkit-column-width: 100px;
  column-width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Example jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3s8007kb/

Comment: This use case looks alright but most major browsers only offer partial support for css columns - http://caniuse.com/#search=column-width